# While creating a new WorkItem of Bug Type how to add value to Severity Field

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

While referring the the following [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130322.aspx) from MSDN site.

From the example the below code for assigning the properties of the newly created code for `WorkItem` object we can assign the value for properties like `Title`,`Description` for the respected `WorkItem` object.

Also referring the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.aspx) Properties and Method there is no way to assign value for `Severity`.

```
WorkItem userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType)
            {

                Title = "Recently ordered menu",
                Description =
                    "Description goes here."
            };
```

Also, I tried to assign with the `Fields` properties but not got success.

```
userStory.Fields["Severity"].Value = "1";
```

Using the latest TFS API.

Answer (score 0):

According to [TFS 2010 API - Create WorkItems(Bugs)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3280.tfs-2010-api-create-workitems-bugs.aspx) you can do it in the following way:

```
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity"].Value = "1-Critical";
```

Comment: How to do it for the latest version of API ?

Comment: @GauravKispotta, I think setting `Severity` like this will work in TFS 2013 as well, give it a try.

Comment: Ya I tried but it did't worked and throws `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException`.

Comment: @GauravKispotta it will be really helpful if you include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem in the question itself, including the exception message and its stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the AllowedValues property for the Severity field:

```
workitem.Fields["Severity"].AllowedValues
```

I think default allowed values are:

- 1 - Critical
- 2 - High
- 3 - Medium
- 4 - Low